# Exporting multiple dataframes into multiple CSV files

Tags: r, csv

I have an issue, I want to export multiple dataframes into multiple .csv files in one for loop. I am not sure how to do it. Let's assume the dataframes are called X, Y, Z, W, and i want them to be exported in one loop into X.csv, Y.csv, Z.csv and W.csv files.

I tried to first make a vector containing names of data frames to be exported:

```
files_to_output <- c("X", "Y", "X", "W")
```

and then did sth like this:

```
for (file_name in files_to_output) {
     filename <- paste0(file_name, ".csv")
     message("Exporting ", filename, " file")
     write,csv(file_name, file.path(glue(input_folder, filename), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

but this is exporting empty data frames

Comment: `write,csv` is a parsing error, try `write.csv` instead. Beyond that, assuming that you have objects named `X`, `Y`, etc, then use `get`, as in `write.csv(get(file_name), file.path(...), ...)`.

Comment: the get(file_name) did the job, thank you!